# С++17 в Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17

Хочу в своем проекте включить компиляцию C++17. Пробывал сделать это следующим образом: Проект -> Свойства -> C/C++ -> Язык -> Стандарт языка C++ -> Стандарт ISO C++17. Нажал применить, но следующий код выводит **201402**, что означает, что компилятор по-прежнему работает с C++14

```
std::cout << _MSVC_LANG << std::endl;
```

В чем проблема? Версия Visual Studio - 15.9.4. Версия Visual C++ - 19.16

Comment: [Тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler%20support) написано, что нужен как минимум 19.11.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, код std::cout << _MSC_VER << std::endl; выводит 1916

Comment: попробовал, работает. Может не сохранили?

Comment: @KoVadim, иду по тому же пути, вижу Стандарт ISO C++17

Comment: тогда показываете сообщение об ошибке

Comment: @KoVadim, вопрос отредактирован

Comment: Выводите значение `std::cout << _MSVC_LANG << "\n";`. Если получите 201402 - с++14, если 201703 - с++17

Comment: @KoVadim, я получил 201402

Comment: Возможно вы включили C++17 только, например, для Debug/x32 версии, а при компиляции стоит x64 и/или Release